# Finding $x$ as expression of $y$?

Tags: functions

I am given the equation $y=(e^x+e^{-x})/(e^x-e^{-x})$
The equation is supposed to be solved in terms of $x$.

Ex: $x= y^2+2y+1$.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Is it supposed to be $e^{-x}$?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, but it is supposed to say e ^ (-x) for 2nd e in numerator and denominator.

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}\implies e^{2x}y-y-e^{2x}=1\implies$$

$$e^{2x}(y-1)=y+1\implies e^{2x}=\frac{y+1}{y-1}\implies 2x=\log\frac{y+1}{y-1}\implies$$

$$x=\frac12\log\frac{y+1}{y-1}$$

By the way, the first $\;y\;$ above is the hyperbolic tangent...

Comment: Reading this 2 hours later. But, out of curiosity, do you have an ELI5 explanation of hyperbolic tangent? This equation was given by my Pre-Calc prof. on a practice sheet, and I have no idea was this means.

Comment: Also what rule of exponents allows me to write the two $e$'s as a singular $e^{2x}$ , so that $1$'s are produced?

Comment: For the hyperbolic sine, cosine, tangent and inverse functions: google it.  For the other thing: I multiplied in the first expression by $\;1=\frac{e^x}{e^x}\;$ ...that's all!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$y=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}\iff y=\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}\iff y(e^{2x}-1)=e^{2x}+1.$$
Set $X=e^{x}$ and you'll have a second degree equation !

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to isolate $x$ in the equation $y=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$. Try setting $t=e^x$ so that $\dfrac{1}{t}=e^x$. Then
$$y=\dfrac{t+\dfrac{1}{t}}{t-\dfrac{1}{t}}$$
and try to isolate $t$. Then use the fact that $x=\ln(t)$.